# which page replacement algorithm android LRUCache class uses?

Tags: android, image-caching

I am using LRU disk cache algorithm as explained [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html#disk-cache). I have some piece of code that works fine for image downloading and caching in memeory and disk cache as well. But I am unable to find out which algorithm this LruCache uses for page replacement?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  What LRU means?  Or how to implement LRU?

Comment: well, as name suggests  LruCache uses LRU alghoritm en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least_Recently_Used